# Remove duplicate edge in directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a directed graph, remove the edge between two nodes if there is an alternate path between them. Ex: given a->b, b->c, a->c, remove a->c. Is there an efficient algorithm to count the number of those removed edges?

Comment: Have you seen [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510277/algorithm-for-finding-redundant-edges-in-a-graph-or-tree)?

Comment: @AxelKemper I didn't find that post, thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm for Finding Redundant Edges in a Graph or Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510277/algorithm-for-finding-redundant-edges-in-a-graph-or-tree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From wiki [Strongly connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component):

> A directed graph is acyclic if and only if it has no strongly connected subgraphs with more than one vertex, because a directed cycle is strongly connected and every nontrivial strongly connected component contains at least one directed cycle.

You can use [Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) to find SCC. And then delete one edge from every component.

Next you need iterate the whole process as *every nontrivial strongly connected component contains at least one directed cycle.*

In general counting number of cycles is NP-hard as if you can count all cycles in polynomial time then you can detect the existence of Hamiltonian cycle as well. But [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) is NP-hard.